# How to arrange icons on Desktop row wise in Ext JS4

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, extjs4

I am having one problem with properly arranging the Desktop Items. 
I **had twelve items to be displayed as shortcut on my Desktop**.

But I am not able to display them correctly in a way of three columns and four rows.

like example :

1==>2==>3==>4

5==>6==>7==>8

9==>10==>11==>12

I am adding my shortcuts with the below mentioned code.

```
shortcuts: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'RT.model.ShortcutModel',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Grid Window',
                    iconCls: 'grid-shortcut',
                    module: 'grid-win'
                },{
                    name: 'Accordion Window',
                    iconCls: 'accordion-shortcut',
                    module: 'acc-win'
                },{
                    name: 'Notepad',
                    iconCls: 'notepad-shortcut',
                    module: 'notepad'
                },{
                    name: 'System Status',
                    iconCls: 'cpu-shortcut',
                    module: 'systemstatus'
                },{
                    name: 'Company Management',
                    iconCls: 'companymgt-shortcut',
                    module: 'companymgt'
                },{
                    name: 'Client Management',
                    iconCls: 'clientmgt-shortcut',
                    module: 'clientmgt'
                },{
                    name: 'HR Management',
                    iconCls: 'hrmgt-shortcut',
                    module: 'hrmgt'
                },{
                    name: 'User Management',
                    iconCls: 'usermgt-shortcut',
                    module: 'usermgt'
                }]
            })
```

**Please provide me proper guidance or any dummy example so i can understand that and implement it correctly**

Answer (score 0):

You could use vbox to draw three containers. Each container has hbox layout and contains your 4 buttons as items.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great site that lets you check out code and examples for different Ext layouts.  I agree with 'DmitryB' that using a layout of `type:'vbox'` is your best bet.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html